# Other options for objects of different types in one collection

Tags: java, oop

I realise that it's generally a bad idea to put objects of different types into one collection, and that I can do it by making the type be "object", but I have a situation where I can't think of an alternative, and was hoping someone else could.

Situation:
At the end of a turn in a game I would like the player to effectively pick up a card from a deck. The card will be one of three types of card. Usually the card will go into the player's hand and allow the player to perform a standard action, but I want there to be a chance of the player getting a special card, with its action being specific to that card, and there to be a chance of the player getting a card which takes its action immediately rather than going into the player's hand. These types cards have nothing in common, so it doesn't seem to make sense to have a common interface, but I want them to be randomly mixed through the deck, so I'd like to have them all in one collection.

Does anyone have any design suggestions? (I'm rather new to OO design)

Comment: They are all cards that can be drawn? They all have a special purpose in the game? So they have something in common or not?

Comment: You should make a common interface or an abstract superclass `Card` for this. I can't imagine that the three types have nothing in common at all. They're all cards, they can be drawn, they have a type.

Comment: They are cards, so they have something in common! Implement a 'Card'-class, and extend it.

Comment: Yes, they can all be drawn, but they do not have the same behaviour upon being drawn, as one type is used immediately whereas the others go to the users hand. It seemed odd to me to have only one method in the abstract class and have it overridden in one of the subclasses, but if this is normal then I'll go for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of using an interface was on the right track. However, you don't need to make the "special action card" implement a `Card` interface: make a different interface for it (say, `Deckable`), make the `Card` interface inherit it, and then implement that interface in your "special action card" class.

```
interface Deckable {
    void takeAction();
}
interface Card extends Deckable {
    int getRank();
    int getSuit();
}
class PlayingCard implements Card {
    ...
}
class SpecialActionCard implements Deckable {
    ...
}
```

Now you can create a list of `Deckable`, and mix your special cards into it:

```
List<Deckable> deck = new ArrayList<Deckable>();
```

Comment: Ah, exactly the sort of idea I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Also interface can have no methods at all and this is normal, for example java.io.Serializable

Comment: @kornero You are correct - it is OK to make an interface with no methods. However, *marker interfaces* should be an exception these days, because you can do a similar thing with an annotation. In fact, had annotations been available at the time, `Serializable` would probably be implemented through them.